# Clarification about @EnableMongoRepositories

Tags: spring, spring-data, maven-profiles, spring-profiles

I'm trying to use @EnableMongoRepositories for using two separate mongo repositories like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(mongoTemplateRef = "mongoBOTemplate", basePackages = "sandbox.dao.bo")
public class BOMongoConfig {

    @Value("#{mongo.hostBO}")
    private String hostBO;

    @Value("#{mongo.databaseBO}")
    private String databaseBO;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoBODbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(hostBO), databaseBO);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoBOTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoBODbFactory());
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplate", basePackages = "sandbox.dao.sandbox")
public class SandboxMongoConfig {

    @Value("#{mongo.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("#{mongo.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(host), database);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

but I'm confused because of this error:

```
710  [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.<init>(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:349)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
```

As I understood there is only one option to fix it is using @Profile. I'm using maven to profile management and not sure why I need hardcore profiles in code...

Could anyone help me with misunderstanding? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to somehow show spring which of those configurations to use for particular case. Otherwise how would it be possible decide which MongoDbFactory instance to create? So yes, use @Profile above both @Configuration classes.

Also please note that maven profiles are not spring profiles. Might be that you dont have to mix maven into that ( if maven profile is only use to set spring one ). I such case you can add `-Dspring.profiles.active=profile` while running your app.

Comment: as I understood there params should help to decide what configuration should be used: mongoTemplateRef and basePackages.

Comment: dop you want to use both databases at once?

Comment: if so - I would no blame EnableMongoRepositories for that exception. Googling seems to result that Environment must not be null! may be result of mixing dependencies' versions.

Comment: yes, I want two datasources for two daos. Datasource1 for dao1, datasource2 for dao2. Why I need configure profiles for this?..

Comment: you dont, I took your suggestion (mentioning Profiles) as you have to turn them on for some cases ( like different env / locale ). As mentioned above - check your spring versions or google exception - it doesnt say a word about mixed repositories configuration